# Increasing Image Contrast in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a greyscale image which has pixel values ranging from 1.000 to 1.003.

I would like to increase the contrast between the different pixels. I have tried `imcontrast` under `imtool`, but I'm not seeing any improvement visually.

Perhaps an idea would be to increase values of pixels >1.000. For example, it would be great if I could map 1.001 to 10, 1.002 to 20 etc. Would that increase contrast?

Comment: when you have a grayscale image with double values, most functions expect those values to lie in the range `[0.0,1.0]`. So no matter how you transform the intensities (linearly or non-linearly), you should then consider mapping the result to the `[0,1]` range.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
newRange = 1.0;  %// choose the new maximum. (new minimum always at 0.0)
imgMin = double(min(image(:)));
imgMax = double(max(image(:)));
image = (image - imgMin) / (imgMax - imgMin) * newRange;
```

Then, you still need to watch for the possibility that the image may be blank (which would cause a divide-by-zero issue).

If the desirable range that you would like to amplify is not the true minimum or maximum, you can set `imgMin` and `imgMax` values manually.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is not exactly what is asked here, but the title of the question may lead others, like me, to come here seeking for a way to (non-destructively) increase contrast in an image *even after it's normalized* — similar to what one can do with the curves feature in Photoshop by setting it to a [sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) shape:

[image: sigmoid curve on photoshop]

A simple way to do this (assuming we have an image normalized in the `[0,1]` range, for instance after passing it through MATLAB's `mat2gray` function) is to use the cosine function. Here's how: we first reflect the cosine curve so that its lowest point is on zero, and the highest on π, rather than the reverse; then we scale the input by π so the highest point occurs when the input has its maximum value, 1; and finally we normalize the result to the output range `[0,1]` (from cosine's original `[-1,1]`) by adding 1 and dividing by 2. The result is the simple formula below:

```
img_contrast = ( -cos( pi * mat2gray( img_original ) ) + 1 ) / 2;
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is display the image with more contrast then you can just use [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/imagesc.html) which scales image data to the full range of the current colormap and displays the image.

If you actually want to adjust the range of the image, you can just normalize it by subtracting the minimum value and dividing by the available range.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `imshow(image, [lowerBound upperBound])` to display the image, it should appear with a linear scaling between the `lowerBound`, which will appear black, and the `upperBound`, which will appear white.  So, for your example, you'd use something like `imshow(image, [1.000 1.003])` to display your image.